# Access a cloud run from another cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am developing an application where i have hosted the frontend in cloud run: public access, no authentication

Another cloud run service has the backend. This requires authentication and is not open to public.

Ofcourse, if I disable authentication on backend service, everything works smoothly.

Is it possible to access the backend with authentication enabled from the frontend cloud run service?

Both the services are in the same serverless VPC.

Comment: This probably fits better on ServerFault, as it's an infrastructure question, not a programming question. That said: when you repost there, I think this needs more specifics. As written, it's fairly open-ended.

Comment: You can communicate from Cloud Run to Cloud Run. But your sentence `access the backend with authentication enabled from the frontend cloud run` lost me. What is your front-end cloud run? Can you describe it?

Comment: How can you know that both services are on the same VPC?

Answer (score 3):

As captured in the [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service), `frontend` can securely and privately invoke `backend` by leveraging the Invoker IAM role:

- Grant the service account of frontend the Cloud Run Invoker IAM role.
- When you issue request from `frontend` to `backend`, you must attach an identity token to the request, see [here for code examples](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#nodejs)

Answer (score 2):

To connect two Cloud Run applications privately, you need to obtain an identity token, and add it to the Authorization header of the outbound request of the target service. You can find documentation and examples here.

For Cloud Run service A (running with service account SA1) to be able to connect to private Cloud Run service B, you need to:

1. Update IAM permissions of service B to give SA1 Cloud Run Invoker role (roles/run.invoker).
2. Obtain an identity token (JWT) from metadata service:

```
curl -H "metadata-flavor: Google" \
      http://metadata/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=URL
```

where URL is the URL of service B (i.e. https://*.run.app).

3. Add header Authentication: Bearer  where  is the response obtained in the previous command.